# PHP возвращает неправильный ответ

Tags: php, строки

```
<?php

$city = "В городе Житомире проживает много людей.";
echo strlen($city);
```

Почему то PHP-скрипт выдаёт результат: 74. Не понимаю почему.

Comment: Потому что `utf-8` или что там у вас.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Функция strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strlen.php) возвращает количество байт, а не число символов в строке. Для utf-8 требуется от 1 до 4 байта на символ.

Используйте [функцию iconv_strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv-strlen.php) - она требует указания кодировки, но вернёт именно количество символов.

Answer (score 1):

```
$city = "В городе Житомире проживает много людей.";
echo mb_strlen($city, 'UTF-8');//кодировку свою только поставьте
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strlen.php

mb_ и iconv по разному с символами работают в некоторых случаях, например при обработке битых символов